# Duplicates in Bigquery partitioned Table

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have seen a issue with the data ,i am trying to find the duplicated data which got inserted on different day partition, now that the problem i want retain the data for older date and delete the latest ingested data.

Ex :- [image]

In the screenshot as you see data is same in two rows but due to some issues same data got inserted into 2021-04-28 as well, Now i want to delete all such records in 2021-04-28 partition. And retain the 04-27 data and actual rows  of 04-28.

Could someone please share the query to find these duplicates and query to get rid of the duplicates that are in 2021-04-28 partition.

Below is the query i have written to identify the duplicates but looks it is not perfectly correct.

```
select grp_nbr,port_rgs_id,tranc_number,strt_tm,sqr_nbr,itm_nbr,trvl_dte from
(select grp_nbr,port_rgs_id,tranc_number,strt_tm,sqr_nbr,itm_nbr,trvl_sdte, row_number() over(partition by grp_nbr,port_rgs_id,tranc_number,strt_tm,sqr_nbr,itm_nbr,trvl_dte order by trvl_dte desc)rn from  table_name)a where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct.
In a more readable way it can be:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(rownum)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp_nbr,port_rgs_id,tranc_number,strt_tm,sqr_nbr,itm_nbr ORDER BY trvl_dte ) rownum
    FROM `yourtable`
    )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

EDIT: the trvl_dte column should not be included in the PARTITION BY statement. Also since you want to keep the earliest trvl_dte, you need to ORDER BY trvl_dte ASC and not DESC.

Comment: This didnot worked, and output is not per my expectation.

Comment: It should work now, did you give it a try ?

Comment: Yes, This worked. I figured out the same , But thank you for the suggestion.