# Combining the filtering of duplicate rows in partitioned table and the query. BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to filter the `customer_id`'s last purchased item from the item purchase table. However, the table is the concatenation of distributed tables and **may contain duplicate rows**. Thus, I am filtering with the `ROW_NUMBER() = 1` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650596/bigquery-deleting-duplicates-in-partitioned-table)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334868/duplicates-in-bigquery-partitioned-table)] which is partitioned by `log_key` field.

I was wondering if there is a better way (instead of using a nested query) of filtering duplicate rows with the same `log_key` and getting the last item purchased by users.

I was wondering if it is possible to combine the two `partition by` operations.

###### currently

```
WITH
purchase_logs AS (
    SELECT
        basis_dt, reg_datetime, logkey,
        customer_id, customer_info_1, customer_info_2,  -- customer info
        item_id, item_info_1, item_info_2,              -- item info
    FROM `project.dataset.item_purchase_table`
    WHERE basis_dt BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-11-10'
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY log_key ORDER BY reg_datetime ASC) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM purchase_logs
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY log_key, customer_id ORDER BY reg_datetime ASC) = 1
ORDER BY reg_datetime, customer_id
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below isn't what I optimally wanted (since the coding format isn't consistent; not filtering `logkey` first). However, I end up combining the two [window operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls) `PARTITION BY` with the prior logic. (I was hoping for some kind of filter with the `HAVING` clause and keeping the coding conventions of filtering with `logkey`.)

```sql
SELECT
    basis_dt, reg_datetime, logkey,
    customer_id, customer_info_1, customer_info_2,  -- customer info
    item_id, item_info_1, item_info_2,              -- item info
FROM `project.dataset.item_purchase_table`
WHERE basis_dt BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-11-10'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY reg_datetime ASC) = 1
;
```